# Multi line text inside fo:inline

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm struggling with my xsl:fo - for generate pdf. I'm trying to generate a Block with inline inline text elements containing 2 lines.

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:inline>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('Title:', $title)"/>
  </fo:inline>
  <fo:leader leader-pattern="space"/>
  <fo:inline>
       <fo:block>Info:</fo:block>
       <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$date"/> </fo:block>
  </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do as is draw in schema?

[image]

Comment: Same code i tried and both block are coming in separate line itself.

Comment: Why don't you use an `<fo:table>`?

Answer (score 0):

What you've drawn looks like a table.

You can put your two blocks into an `fo:inline-container` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container):

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length.optimum="50%" />
    <fo:inline>
        title
    </fo:inline>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length.optimum="50%" />
    <fo:inline-container alignment-baseline="middle">
        <fo:block>Info:</fo:block>
        <fo:block>date</fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
</fo:block>
```

---

An even more table-like alternative:

```
<fo:block text-align="center">
    <fo:inline-container width="80%">
        <fo:block>title</fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container><fo:inline-container alignment-baseline="middle" width="20%">
        <fo:block>Info:</fo:block>
        <fo:block>date</fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
</fo:block>
```

---

And as a table:

```
<fo:table width="100%" text-align="center">
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell width="80%" display-align="center">
                <fo:block>title</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell width="20%">
                <fo:block>Info:</fo:block>
                <fo:block>date</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, items marked as `fo:inline-container`  do not appear in my preview
https://i.imgur.com/OOyUkXy.png Both `fo: inline-container` and `fo: block-container` do not work

Comment: It works for me with AH Formatter.  Your "title" is off-center, so your formatter may be taking the `leader-length.optimum` too literally, which would make the `fo:inline-container` overflow the containing area.  I have added an alternative that uses two `fo:inline-container`, both with a fixed width. However, the FO markup would be easier for someone else to comprehend if you just used an `fo:table` to achieve the effect.

Comment: How can i merge two cells in table? `number-rows-spanned=" "`  dont work for me.

Comment: A literal space shouldn't work. `number-rows-spanned="2"` should work.